# Prefixes in variable names and multiple new data frames in loops in R

Tags: r, dataframe

The data frames Day1 and Day2 each contain variable names with prefixes (rad_ and tv_, and you_ and pho_ respectively). Each data frame also contains variable names without a prefix, and to these variable names I'd like to add a prefix (`noncom_`). Finally, I'd like to create new data frames, NewDay1 and NewDay2, that are partially named after the original data frames but in which all variable names have prefixes. In reality there are numerous data frames, so I'm aiming for a general solution. Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (dfs):

```
Day1 <- data.frame("rad_cat"=c(NA,NA,NA),"tv_dog"=c(NA,NA,NA) ,"tv_turkey_E3"=c(NA,NA,NA), "zebra_E2"=c(NA,NA,NA), "elephant"=c(NA,NA,NA))
Day2 <- data.frame("you_cat"=c(NA,NA,NA),"pho_horse_E3_E6"=c(NA,NA,NA) ,"pho_cow_E4_E4_E1"=c(NA,NA,NA), "hippo_E1"=c(NA,NA,NA), "lion_E4_E1"=c(NA,NA,NA))
```

Desired outcome (dfs):

```
NewDay1 <- data.frame("rad_cat"=c(NA,NA,NA),"tv_dog"=c(NA,NA,NA) ,"tv_turkey_E3"=c(NA,NA,NA), "noncom_zebra_E2"=c(NA,NA,NA), "noncom_elephant"=c(NA,NA,NA))
NewDay2 <- data.frame("you_cat"=c(NA,NA,NA),"pho_horse_E3_E6"=c(NA,NA,NA) ,"pho_cow_E4_E4_E1"=c(NA,NA,NA), "noncom_hippo_E1"=c(NA,NA,NA), "noncom_lion_E4_E1"=c(NA,NA,NA))
```

Attempt so far:

```
library(dplyr)
dfs <- list(Day1, Day2)  
numdfs <- length(dfs)
for (i in 1:numdfs) 
{
  dfa <- dfs[i] %>% select(-matches("rad_|tv_")) %>% setNames(paste0('noncom_', names(.)))
  dfb <- dfs[i] %>% select(matches(c("rad_|tv_")))
  dfc <- cbind(dfa,dfb)  ]
  name<-paste("New",dfs[i],sep="")
  assign(name, dfc))
}
```

Comment: Are there numerous prefixes as well? Or you have just these 4 ? (rad_ and tv_, and you_ and pho_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function, `rename_fun`, to add the prefix to those without your defined prefix. After that, we can use `lapply` to apply this function to all the data frame.

```
library(magrittr)

rename_fun <- function(x, prefix = "noncom_"){
  x2 <- x %>%
    setNames(ifelse(!grepl("rad_|tv_|you_|pho_", names(.)), paste0(prefix, names(.)), names(.)))
  return(x2)
}

lapply(list(Day1, Day2), rename_fun)
[[1]]
  rad_cat tv_dog tv_turkey_E3 noncom_zebra_E2 noncom_elephant
1      NA     NA           NA              NA              NA
2      NA     NA           NA              NA              NA
3      NA     NA           NA              NA              NA

[[2]]
  you_cat pho_horse_E3_E6 pho_cow_E4_E4_E1 noncom_hippo_E1 noncom_lion_E4_E1
1      NA              NA               NA              NA                NA
2      NA              NA               NA              NA                NA
3      NA              NA               NA              NA                NA
```

#### Update

The output of `lapply` is a list. We can store the output to an object and use the following way to access each data frame.

```
Day_list <- lapply(list(Day1, Day2), rename_fun)

NewDay1 <- Day_list[[1]]
NewDay2 <- Day_list[[2]]
```

Comment: In the solution provided by ycw, how do I turn the output into separate data frames? I tried as.data.frame(lapply(list(Day1, Day2), rename_fun)), but then it becomes a single data frame, containing both Day1 and Day2.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `rename_at` which applies a function to a subset of column names.

The `vars` parameter describes what column names we want to change. In this case, it is every column except ones that start with a prefix.

The next parameter is the function we want to apply to the chosen column names.

```
library('tidyverse')

set_prefixes <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    rename_at(
      vars(
        -starts_with('rad_'),
        -starts_with('tv_'),
        -starts_with('you_'),
        -starts_with('pho_')),
      ~stringr::str_c('noncom_', .x))
}

map(list(Day1, Day2), set_prefixes)
# [[1]]
#   rad_cat tv_dog tv_turkey_E3 noncom_zebra_E2 noncom_elephant
# 1      NA     NA           NA              NA              NA
# 2      NA     NA           NA              NA              NA
# 3      NA     NA           NA              NA              NA
# 
# [[2]]
#   you_cat pho_horse_E3_E6 pho_cow_E4_E4_E1 noncom_hippo_E1 noncom_lion_E4_E1
# 1      NA              NA               NA              NA                NA
# 2      NA              NA               NA              NA                NA
# 3      NA              NA               NA              NA                NA
```

If you want to use regex instead of `starts_with` you can do the following:

```
set_prefixes <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    rename_at(
      vars(-matches('rad_|tv_|you_|pho_')),
      ~stringr::str_c('noncom_', .x))
}
```